# Parsing formal language with the parameterized sets of symbols (how to handle evolving grammars with Yacc apart from recompiling)?

Tags: parsing, logic, yacc, context-free-grammar

I am trying to build a parser (using Yacc) for [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Alphabet) languages but I am a bit confused. FOL can have many languages — each language can have its own sets of functions, relations, named variables. So, small languages may be general and include very few symbols like `animal`, `human`, `object`. But rich languages can be very specific and include very many symbols like `cat`, `dog`, `monkey`, `John`, `Peter`, `table`, `spoon`, etc.

Is there way to introduce the parameterized set of symbols whose set can be of almost infinite length, like `f(1)`, `f(2)`, `f(3)`, `f(i)`,... and then there can be both specific grammar rules for specific and general grammar rules like ones that are connected with `f(i) for even i` and `f(j) for odd j`. I have heard about https://www.grammaticalframework.org/ and categorical grammars which have categories, but they have a fixed set of constants too.

So - I guess, that - if I would like to make my system open and be ready to accommodate growing symbols, then I should be ready to update grammar and use Yacc to recompile parser and make some generalized classes?

Is there an approach to handle evolving grammars in the software code? Can Yacc do that?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of specific grammar rules which need to be introduced? (Or even a reference which shows these, unlike the Wikipedia page.) If your concern is guaranteeing that functions and predicates are used with the correct valence, then it's true that the solution is slightly outside yacc's capabilities. But it's easy to fix in a semantic action.

Comment: If you've not already done so, read Hofstadter's [Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0465026567).  It sounds a bit as if you want to write a program that can recognize specifications for FOL languages in general, and that can compile and run the grammar for any specific FOL.  If I'm interpreting what you're asking about, then it is pretty tricky to do.

Comment: But isn't we doing this as a programmers all the time - just - via compiling? We have grammar for specifying functions and Boolean expressions (FOL formulas) and then we compile that it the instruction set. Maybe we have to have language for writing FOL grammar (define functions, relations, variables) and then let it be compiled into FOL theory in FOL language and then some deduction engine can execute it. Just idea. I am reading about compilation, parsing and about Golden Braid now. Thanks.